# Column break in HTML/php coding issue

Tags: php, html, tcpdf

I have a SQL pupil's list sorted by classes and this list goes into TCPDF to create a PDF 2 columned list. My issue is that I can't find the way to break the line.

What I know is that a column can have max 59 rows. So, if the next group would not fit they should go to the next column.

The theory would be to check the actual line

```
$html=$html.'<tr><td width="40">&nbsp;</td><td width="90">&nbsp;</td><td width="50">&nbsp;</td><td width="45">&nbsp;</td><td width="45">&nbsp;</td></tr>'; //35
while($classok = mysql_fetch_array($classquery))
{

$classes=$classok['id'];
$classnum=mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("SELECT class_id FROM pupils  WHERE class_id=".$classes." AND pupils.torolve=0 and pupils.statusz=1"));
```

I would like here something that would shift the rows down if the next class would reach more than 59 lines. Like:

```
$html=$html.'<tr><td></td></tr>';
```

but I can't put the condition in the right way...

The problem is that the previous group randomly finishes so the next class should start the on the new page.

```
$headek=$headek.'<b><tr><th>D.O.B.</th><th colspan="2">';
$headek=$headek.$classok['name'].'</th><th colspan="2">';
$headek=$headek.$classok['initname'];

$sum=$sum+$classnum;
$headek=$headek.'('.$classnum.')'.'</th></tr></b>';
$html=$html.strtoupper($headek);

$pupilssql="SELECT pupils.extra_functions, pupils.name, pupils.dateofbirth, pupils.sex, YEAR(pupils.dateofbirth) AS year, MONTH(pupils.dateofbirth) AS month, DAY(pupils.dateofbirth) AS days, pupils.name, pupils.firstname, pupils.class_id FROM pupils, classes  WHERE pupils.class_id=classes.id AND pupils.torolve=0 and pupils.statusz=1 AND class_id=".$classes." ORDER BY  pupils.name ASC";
$pupilsquery=mysql_query($pupilssql);
while($result = mysql_fetch_array($pupilsquery))
{
etc...
```

Everything is working well except this column break that I can't put in code... Anyone's help would be appreciated.

Comment: It is REALLY hard to understand what the problem is.  You would be well served with a diagram I think.  Where do you want the break?  What do you have to shift down?  Why can't you use modulus to solve the problem.  Please give more detail so people can help.  An example picture that shows it looking wrong would be a big help here.

Comment: Sorry I am going to provide more information tomorrow I just need to collect them. Thanks again for any help.

Answer (score 0):

They will need to be separate tables. Start a new table for each block of 59 pupils and then use CSS to float the tables so they will stack up next to each other. Or you can be lazy and put those tables inside a table and do EZ formatting (yuck).

Comment: Thanks guy, the problem is I don't know where is the end of the last group as the length is 'random'. Any idea on that?

Answer (score 0):

Add a variable before your loop: `$i = 0;`

Iterate it at the beggining of your loop: `$i++;`

At the end of your loop, use if and modulus to print whatever seperator you want every 59 (or however many) lines: `if($i % 59 == 0) echo '<br />';`

*change `<br />` to whatever code you need to seperate the sections*

Comment: Thanks guy, the problem is I don't know where is the end of the last group as the length is 'random'. Any idea on that?

Comment: You need some way to test if your at the end of your group. In this case, I kept count and we tested that it was not evenly divisible by 59. You just need to figure out what your test is and use that.

Comment: I know I just can't find the right way how many lines I need to insert between.